# OpenCL image filter iterations without returning to host?

Tags: opencl

I don't have my code in front of me, but i'm doing a common scenario where an image is sampled, written to, repeat. Each iteration of this requires me to read the result back to the CPU and throw it back to OpenCL again. The limitation is that an image is either read or write, not both. Is there a way I can do all this in the Kernel rather than looping it back to the CPU?

Comment: You might want to clarify your question a bit further. Whats keeping you from creating the images as readwrite and using them in a ping-pong like approach (change each iteration which image you read and which you write)?

Comment: There is no need to read the result back to the CPU (do you mean RAM?). The only limitation with read/write images is that reading data that was written to in the same kernel call will return undefined results (see Nvidia OpenCL Programming Guide). If that is a problem for you, then you could have two images, one to read from, one to write to, and switch them after each iteration. So please elaborate on that point, what exactly forces you to involve the CPU. Otherwise one can't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to read result back to host, but you need to rewrite your algorithm to use several step with additional textures to store intermediate results.